# Open Google Chrome in Incognito Mode?

Tags: google-chrome, switch

Is there any way (perhaps some target switch?) to place a Google Chrome shortcut in my quick launch tray and have it open in incognito mode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a shortcut to Chrome, in the Properties window add `-incognito` to the Target box.

[image]

(image from [here](http://www.techdreams.org/tips-tricks/create-desktop-shortcut-to-launch-chrome-in-incognito-mode-by-default/603-20081208))

Comment: should be -- not - (double dash, not a single dash), no?

Comment: @hansen: I just tried it. I will work either way.