# How to stop Google Chrome from starting in Incognito mode?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, crunchbang, private-browsing

I am using Linux Crunchbang with Openbox on my Acer Aspire 5536 laptop. When I click on the Google Chrome icon it starts in Incognito mode. How can I stop that, so it starts normally?

Comment: It is a good idea to include the Desktop Environment you are using and to specify where the icon is located. On the desktop? on a shortcut launch bar? On a 3rd party panel? What is the command that this icon launches (right click=>Edit or properties or similar)?

Comment: OP: Double check your launcher for Google Chrome, to launch in incognito you would use `google-chrome --incognito`, so look for that and remove `--incognito`.  Since it's probably using the `tint2` panel by default, you may actually need to adjust the *.desktop file that the launcher links to (Tint2 usually pulls that from the `~/.config/tint2/tint2rc`)  Though, that shouldn't be enabled by default...

Comment: What version of Chrome. Have you looked at the Chrome configuration settings for an option that disabled incognito mode when a new session is started?  This question and answer should help you: http://superuser.com/questions/9304/open-google-chrome-in-incognito-mode?rq=1

Comment: i am using tint2 panel and the version of Chrome says 23.0.1271.97